# Buggy window titles and buttons in Ubuntu 16.04 (VM)

Tags: 16.04, vmware, window, virtualization

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on a virtual machine (VMware Workstation Pro 12) to test it out. Everything works fine except for one thing, the window titles and the close, maximize and minimize buttons are supper buggy, I tried to do some software updates but it didn't fixed the problem, i also re-installed the OS but the bug is still there. I had a Ubuntu 14.04 Vm and it worked like a charm.

PD: I am a total Linux noob

[image: See image here]